# Windows 10 UWP App: MissingMethodException on GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

When trying to authenticate using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync in a Windows 10 UWP app (using the portable libraries available on NuGet, v1.9.1), the following exception occurs:

Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in mscorlib.ni.dll

Additional information: Method not found: 'System.Uri Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl.Build()'.

I dug around in the api code and the method is there. Any help on this?

Comment: Can you try to reinstall the NuGet packages? I didn't test the library for Windows 10... so it might be that there is a different in this Windows version...

Comment: I already tried reinstalling the packages. I also checked the file copied to the output folder and it seems to be the right version. Using dotPeek I checked the dll and the 'missing method' is in fact there.

Comment: Have you tried 1.20 version of the package?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. the same nuget pakcage is installed **both** in the .core & and main UWP projects.
2. the nuget packages in different projects are the **same version**